# Self Referencing or Separate Redundant Tables in Entity Relationship diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I have a case where employees submit peer reviews for each other. A recipient requests feedback and submitter(one or more) submit feedback. An Employee cannot self-review.

1) Can I use one table as 'Employee' and use it as 2 instances such as Recipient and Submitter?

2) Can I use 'Employee' table and then self-reference it to avoid any redundancy? I am trying to think how I can do this with constraints such employee cannot submit its own review by applying a condition as employee ID should not be equal while submitting/requesting feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where do you see that redundancy, but something like this should work.

---

[image: employeee_review]

Answer (score 0):

1) You can have a relation with two roles which are both filled by employees. However, don't confuse rows/tables with entities/entity types.

2) I assume employees can submit feedback more than once as well as receive feedback more than once. If so, you have a many-to-many relation which can't be denormalized into the Employee table with introducing redundancy. A separate table with a check constraint to prevent the submitter from being equal to the recipient sounds appropriate.